# Windows 10 settings not opening from Start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

In my new laptop, the Windows 10 search for settings works, but when I click on one of those results nothing happens.

For example, if I search for "touchpad":

[image: search for touchpad]

The item appears, however if I click on it, nothing happens. And I mean, *nothing*, the Start menu is not even being closed.

However, the results for the old settings work (the ones highlighted would work, the ones with the red `!` won't):

[image: old settings]

If I search for "Settings" and open the control panel, I can navigate to those settings. So it's not a problem with Settings itself, but with the search results (I think):

[image: Settings app]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have UAC disabled.  Settings is a Windows Store/Modern UI/Universal Windows Program, UAC must be enabled, for UWPs to function.

Comment: Same problem here.  Started a couple days ago.

Comment: @Ramhound no, UAC is enabled. It's the default. It's a brand new computer, 2 weeks of use.

Comment: FWIW I rebooted (duh) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and found a [blog post](https://blogencounters.com/201803/windows-10-settings-will-not-open-start-menu/) with a fix that worked for me.

Run the following in an elevated powershell prompt:

```
Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}

Get-appxpackage -allusers | foreach {add-appxpackage -disabledevelopmentmode -register “$($_.installlocation)\appxmanifest.xml”}
```

And then restart your machine